# 1 to many relationship in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two fact tables in Power BI,
One table with the order id and metric tons. Another table with the invoice number, order id and the amount invoiced.
An order id can have more invoice numbers (one to many relationship).

If I want to have an overview of all my orders, with the metric tons and the amount invoiced, I only see the order id's for which an invoice number exists, but I also want to see the order id's for which there are no invoices, so we know there are no invoices yet for that order.
The only way I can think of now is to create dummy invoice records with an amount of zero, for those orders, but I think there is a better way to solve this problem in Power BI.

[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8cA0.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqG5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Metric tons has to be a summarizable.
It's also important to use the order id of the correct table. (Order id of orders instead of Invoices)

Here's the [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hz9H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

can you make a screenshot of the relation how you'd make it!
maybe this will help answering your question.

with this information I think you might have switched the entities around a bit. but to be sure I really need a screenshot of you're relationship.

if the relationship is correct there might be a many to many relationship which can only be made possible if you introduce a connect-table which contains the items from both tables (only the items you want to be connected that way)

Comment: I have added the Relations screenshot to my original post, and the Power BI Output as well. On the left side on the output there is the data of the orders and the invoices. On the right side the output of the combined data. I would like to see the line for order 3,4,5 as well, with their metric tons and an amount of zero, because there are no invoices.

Comment: this is not possible with this set-up because you have a 1 to may relationship.

it will Always have 1 in the left outer and 1 or many on the right. to do this i suggest you make a calculated column where both tables will be linked at with the attributes you want. there you can setup an if-statement which will contain a expression which says something like when the column "invoice" is empty it will say "unknown" or "null" if there is an "invoice" then show "invoice"

i hope this will help you get the result you want!